# Read response from http get request

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can i read an init response from a http get? Basicly my code is this, but i can't reach these objects.

```
var request = require("request")
request({
    url: "http://xxx/xxx/get.php?act=init&aparam=parame",
    method:"get",
     json: true
}, function (error, response, body) {
console.log(response.toJSON);// why i cant reach every object etc from here like this




   });
```

Response is like that

```
IncomingMessage {
  _readableState: 
   ReadableState {
     objectMode: false,
     highWaterMark: 16384,
     buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
     length: 0,
     pipes: null,
 },.../// continues...
```

Comment: What is your response returning?

Comment: I think what you're trying to access is the body, the body is the one that contains the actual data returned from the endpoint. the response is an http.IncomingMessage object (Response object). You can read more about it here https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage

Comment: i am trying to reach an init response that may has some data in it, i dk, how can i find a array data in response

Answer (score 2):

from https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

you can access result from `body` param, like this

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred 
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received 
  console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage. 
});
```